# SQL - consulta registros Verdadeiros ou Falsos

Tags: sql, asp, microsoft-access, vbscript

Estou montando uma página simples que mostram registros marcados como bloqueados pelo admin. O campo é user-block e as opções são FALSE ou TRUE.

Imaginei que a Query seria:

```
"Select * from Usuarios WHERE user-block = "&TRUE&" order by NOME asc"
```

Mas este select retorna erro de falta de parâmetros

Alguém consegue me explicar o que há de errado com a instrução?

Comment: é ASP VB Script com banco Access?

Comment: sim, Virgilio. É isto mesmo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta a sua é funcional, mas, tem problemas com desempenhos.

Answer (score 1):

O correto na sua [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) seria:

```
Select * from Usuarios WHERE [user-block]=true order by NOME asc
```

simplesmente por causa do traço (`-`) você tem que colocar colchetes (<kbd>[</kbd> e <kbd>]</kbd>), e não seria muito legal fazer assim, procure colocar os campos com [underscore](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore), ou seja, traço embaixo exemplo `user_block`, mas, isso resolveria a sua duvida.

***Código completo***

```
<%

    dim connection
    dim result

    set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    set result = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

    connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\adm.mdb"


    result.Open "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE [user-block]=true", connection



    Do While Not result.EOF
        Response.Write(result.Fields("Id") & " - ")
        Response.Write(result.Fields("Nome") & " - ")
        Response.Write(result.Fields("user-block"))
        Response.Write("<br />")

        result.MoveNext
    Loop

    connection.Close
    set connection = Nothing
%>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Underscore](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore)
- [ADO - Como usar o objeto Connection ?](http://www.macoratti.net/connect.htm)
- [ASP e ADO - Colocando seu banco de dados na WEB](http://www.macoratti.net/aspado.htm)
- [Trabalhando com Recordsets - Alterando e Retornando dados.](http://www.macoratti.net/dao_ado2.htm)
- [Using the Recordset with MS Access and ADO](https://www.aspfree.com/c/a/microsoft-access/using-the-recordset-with-ms-access-and-ado/)

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Basta filtrar os registros depois de selecioná-los:

```
sSQL = "Select * from Usuarios order by nome asc"       

set RStemp = createobject("adodb.recordset")
set RStemp.activeconnection = usersDB

regs = 10
pag = 1

RStemp.cursortype = 3
RStemp.pagesize = regs
RStemp.open sSQL
TotalInscritos = RStemp.RecordCount
RStemp.filter = "user-block = TRUE"
```

Espero que a solução seja útil para outros

Comment: Não seria ideal, porque acaba trazendo tudo que tem na sua base de dados, e depois fazer um filtro, é melhor já vir filtrado, isso acarreta desempenho ruim. Na minha resposta a solução para o determinado campo.